# MySql-5.1.40 fullText search doesn't work in MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

1. The MySQL version is 5.1.40
2. The table is MyISAM(only changed the table to MyISAM)
3. The type of table_column(name) is varchar

When I apply the fullText search, it doesn't work.

## Below sql only return data 'eeee', will not return such as 'eeeefff' or 'ffeeee'

```
select name from test where match(name) against('eeee' in boolean mode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's full text search lets you search for keywords *beginning*, but not ending, in a certain substring.  So, to find all words beginning with `eeee` we can try:

```
SELECT name
FROM test
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('eeee*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Tim, got it. Thanks for your answer.